# Swift - cocoapod circular slider

Tags: swift, swift3, cocoapods, hgcircularslider

I am trying to use CircularSlider in my app.

I found the following two module
https://github.com/taglia3/CircularSlider
https://cocoapods.org/pods/HGCircularSlider

This is what I did

```
$pod init
```

and this is my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Dr.FOOD' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Dr.FOOD
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'HGCircularSlider', '~> 1.0.3'
  pod 'CircularSlider'

end
```

and then, what I did

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using CircularSlider (1.1.2)
Using Firebase (3.11.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.6.0)
Using FirebaseCore (3.4.6)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.1.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Using HGCircularSlider (1.0.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Dr.FOOD.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 5 dependencies from the Podfile and 10 total pods installed.
```

I'm using the .xcworkspace but it still says
"No such module 'HGCircularSlider'" in my code.

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: clean and build the code

Comment: @GaneshKumar clean and build the code ?

Comment: pleasee stop or close xcode and then install pod

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I do when I add a new pod, in addition to what you did already.

- Open the workspace file, go to the project settings page:

[image]

- Scroll down and you'll see this:

[image]

- Click on the `+` button and add all the frameworks you wish.
- Command + B to build the project.
- Now import the modules

Comment: @jlassap If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: it says i can check that in 40 seconds.. i'll do that later ! thank you

Comment: This is not a correct answer, you shouldn't do that when using Cocaopods, the issue the @jlassap was having is just related to cleaning and rebuilding the project. avoiding manually adding frameworks and configuring the project is why we use Cocoapods in the first place.